# How do I change input selection after my wallet provides an unfavorable choice?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, available-outputs, output-selection

I had 5 monero (XMR) in my wallet yesterday, made up a single 5 XMR output.  This morning I sent this wallet 20.5 XMR, so now I have 25.5 XMR total.

Now I want to "churn" the recently received 20.5 XMR input (whether needed or not), so I created a transfer transaction to send 20 XMR to myself.  `monero-wallet-cli` asked me if it was okay to use the 20.5 XMR output *and* the 5 XMR output as inputs to the transaction.

It asked me if this was okay, and I said it was not, so the transaction canceled.  I retried several times, and it always gives me the same mix.  I don't want a mix of outputs at all.  I want to just send the 20.5 output only.  Is there a way to do this?  I would expect that a second try or third try would change the output selection, but it didn't.

(I'm wondering if there will be a way in the future, but it's just not yet coded.  Would I create a github issue in that case?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your particular case: use the latest version of monero-wallet-cli, and `set min-outputs-count 1000`. This will tell the wallet to not include a second unneeded input. However, your transaction will look different from the majority of other transactions, which tend to have 2 inputs. As this new code gets used more and more though, there will be a good mix of 1 and 2 input transactions.

In the general case, though, it is more complicated, and depends on the amount sent and your particular owned output set (and I won't go into details because it's complicated, not really relevant, and subject to change). Sometimes there will be a random selection, and sometimes not.